# PHP 5.4.4 vs PHP 5.4.28 both with xdebug performance issue

Tags: php, performance, xdebug

I just updated PHP on my dev environment from 5.4.4 to 5.4.28 and faced with performance issue. Both versions have xdebug installed.

Here is small benchmark witten in PHP: http://pastebin.com/aFs70Ds7
Here are my results (total time):

5.4.4 - 11.8 seconds

5.4.28 - 20.4 seconds

So, almost two times slower.

Here are phpinfo's for both PHP versions:

5.4.4 - http://pastebin.com/kRsUrW2K

5.4.28 - http://pastebin.com/2wma9kSD

Can anyone help me with this performance issue? Thank you.

Regards,
Alex.

Comment: Have you made sure that the issue is related to xdebug? Does the performance regression also take place if you disable xdebug temporary?

Comment: I made tests on both versions without xdebug enabled and got same results - 3 seconds for both - no performance regression.

Comment: I can confirm this with the shown script. Without xdebug 5.4.29 is  faster than 5.4.4. However when using xdebug in conjunction with the linked benchmark 5.4.29 performs worse than 5.4.4. While it is expected that xdebug decreases the performance it was unexpected that the older versions seems to work better with newer php versions. Using XDebug 2.2.1 on 5.4.29 decreases the gap to an more or less acceptable width. Conclusion: **Don't use debugging tools on a production environment/whenever you care about performance**. Still, this is an artificial benchmark no conclusion how real apps work

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. With xdebug version 2.2.3 PHP 5.4.28 works as fast as PHP 5.4.4 with xdebug version 2.2.1.
The problem was with xdebug version 2.2.5.